# Privilegies of command inside shell script

Tags: shell-script, permissions, scripting, sudo, su

I need to run simple script to check host status (ping),

I have following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Host checker:"
if [ "`ping -c 1 172.17.10.1`" ]
then
  echo "HOST UP"
else
  echo "HOST DOWN"
fi
```

Following permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sysadmin users   142 Jul 13 16:14 lgchk.sh
```

When issuing ping from bash all is ok:

```
sysadmin@host:~$ ping 172.17.10.1
PING 172.17.10.1 (172.17.10.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.159 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.186 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.10.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.203 ms
```

But whe run the script i got error:

```
sysadmin@host:~$ ./lgchk.sh
Host checker:
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
HOST DOWN
```

If I will run ping inside the script as follows:

```
...
if [ "`su -u sysadmin ping -c 1 172.17.10.1`" ]
...
```

All will be ok, but it will ask for password.

Could you please suggest why it happens and how to fix it? 
Is privileges of command inside the script differs from privileges in command line?

Comment: Is there any chance that `ping` is a shell alias, so that it does different things on the command prompt and from a script?

Comment: @dhag
Thank you, really ping is as "sudo /bin/ping" in alias. Did the same in script and it works

Answer (score 1):

have you tried sudo ?

```
if sudo -u sysadmin  /bin/ping -c ...
```

you must edit /etc/sudoers as root with

```
%g1 ALL=(sysadmin) NOPASSWD:  /bin/ping
```

to allow people group group `g1` to run ping command.

see `man sudo`, `man sudoers` and https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password for details.

Comment: I don't have root/sudo privileges, so can't do that.

I can execute ping from shell (user 'sysadmin'), but can't do it from script(the same 'sysadmin user')

Answer (score -1):

Probably your `ping` executable is missing the SUID bit. When you run

```
ls -l $(which ping)
```

you should see something like this:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 38200 Jul 23  2015 /bin/ping
```

probably you do not have the `s` permission on the the 4th character from the beginning of line. Solution is simple. Run command:

```
chmod u+s `which ping`
```

as root or using `su` or `sudo`

Comment: I think you are refering to SUID bit.
ping is without it: 

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root bin 69204 Mar 28  2007 /bin/ping*

I don't have root/sudo privileges, so I can't set SUID bit.

In any case I don't understand why when I run in shell ping as 'sysadmin' all is ok, but when I run it inside script (that has user: sysadmin too) I got an error?